# Facing Error in updating value in two table in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function update(Request $request, $user)
{

    $user= User::find($user);
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $mobile= Mobile::find($user);
    $mobile->id = $request->input('id');
    $mobile->country_code = $request->input('country_code');
    $mobile->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
    $user->save();

return redirect('/dashboard')->with('alert-success', 'updated');
    }
```

this code is not working for me ... i want to update the value in two table one table is (user) and second table is (mobile)..

Comment: what kind of error you are getting??

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Is it giving an error or just not doing what you want? If the latter, try including `$mobile->save()`

Comment: do you have relation between `User` and `Mobile` model ?

Comment: i will post my controller and other things

Comment: what is `Mobile::find($user)` meant to achieve?

Comment: where i am getting the value

Comment: my Model one is User and one is Mobile

Answer (score 0):

You are not committing the changes to the `Mobile` model to your database.

Calling `$model->save()` commits any changes to the *that instance* of *that model object*, to the database.

However, it looks like you're using the wrong value to 'find' the mobile model. If you're using Laravel relationships correctly, my edit to that part should help.

I tend to handle changes to my models individually in my code, so it is more readable. Here's how I would do it:

```
$user= User::find($user);
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->save();

$mobile = $user->mobile //this part relies on you having set up the relationship correctly.
$mobile->id = $request->input('id');
$mobile->country_code = $request->input('country_code');
$mobile->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
$mobile->save();
```

Comment: public function edit(Authenticatable $user)
    {
        $editinfo = Mobile::find($user);
        return view('edit',compact('user'));
    }   this is my edit function in my controller

Comment: ? I have no idea why you have made the above comment.

Comment: no this is my edit controller to tell you i am just getting data fro mobile

Comment: please tell me how to do?

Comment: giving me error  this is my edit controller                                                                                          
  public function edit(Authenticatable $user)
    {
        $editinfo = Mobile::find($user);
        return view('edit',compact('user'));
    }

Comment: should i need to use the User also in function

Answer (score 0):

### Edit A Form

```
   <form class="" action="{{ route('user.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST" name="">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
       <input type="text" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
          {{ csrf_field() }} 

          <Input  type="text"  name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" >
          <Input  type="text"  name="email" value="{{$user->email}}" >

        @if($user->mobile)

         <Input  type="text"  name="country_code" value="{{$user->mobile->country_code}}">
          <Input  type="text"  name="phone_number" value=" {{$user->mobile->phone_number}}">
        @else
      <Input  type="text"  name="country_code" value="{{$user->mobile->country_code}}">
          <Input  type="text"  name="phone_number" value=" {{$user->mobile->phone_number}}">
        @endif

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="" >update</span></button>
          <span class="pull-right">


</div>
```

its my edit.blade.php

controller for edit
        $editinfo = Mobile::find($user);
        return view('edit',compact('user'));

Answer (score 0):

You are not perform`save()` on `$mobile` instance
are you forgot add `$mobile->save()`

Answer (score 0):

you could use tap()function

```
$user= User::findOrFail($id);
$user_update = tap($user)->update([
    'country_code' => $request->input('country_code'),
    'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
]);
```

further read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-tap